# Change Number Format

Tags: regex, sed, awk

I have a lot lines contains `XXXXXXXXX-XXX.XXX` number format. I want change number `XXXXXXXXX-XXX.XXX` to `XX.XXX.XXX.X-XXX.XXX`

`XXXXXXXXX-XXX.XXX` = 15 digit random number

Anyone can help me? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is ugly (because sed uses [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regex#POSIX_.28Portable_Operating_System_Interface_.5Bfor_Unix.5D.29) regex), but should work:

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{3\}\)\([0-9]\{3\}\)\([0-9]\)\(-[0-9]\{3\}\.[0-9]\{3\}\)/\1.\2.\3.\4\5/g'
```

Answer (score 2):

General regex: Search for `(\d{2})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d)-(\d{3}\.\d{3})` and replace with `\1.\2.\3.\4-\5`.

I don't know sed well enough, but I think the syntax there is a bit different. Try this:

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{3\}\)\([0-9]\{3\}\)\([0-9]\)-\([0-9]\{3\}\.[0-9]\{3\}\)/\1.\2.\3.\4-\5/')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 echo "987654321" | sed 's/\([0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9]\)/\1.\2.\3.\4/'
```

(this outputs 98.765.432.1)

Then, for reading input from a file:

```
sed 's/\([0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9]\)/\1.\2.\3.\4/' in.txt
```

and, for writing to a new file:

```
sed 's/\([0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9]\)/\1.\2.\3.\4/' in.txt > out.txt
```

I guess you could refine it, but that's the general idea.